# Using DataTables with momentjs in Angular 6 gets fn.dataTable.moment is not a function

Tags: jquery, angular, sorting, datatable, momentjs

so I'm kinda frustraded since this issue seems so simple but yet i can't seem to fix it.

I'm using a DataTable (which works fine) - now i want to make a column containing dates sortable by the german date format dd.MM.yyyy.

I found the documentation on the datatables homepage: https://datatables.net/blog/2014-12-18

But when i try to use the plugin it gives me this error:

```
core.js:1673 ERROR TypeError: jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__.fn.dataTable.moment is not a function
    at help.component.ts:82
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:3815)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
    at push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask (zone.js:496)
    at ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:485)
    at timer (zone.js:2054)
```

My Setup looks like this:

angular.json

```
"scripts": [
  "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js",
  "node_modules/moment/min/moment.min.js",
  "node_modules/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js",
  "node_modules/datatables.net-plugins/sorting/datetime-moment.js",
  "node_modules/datatables.net-plugins/sorting/date-de.js"
]
```

component.ts

```
import * as $ from "jquery";

// console.log(moment(new Date()).toJSON()); -> moment itself also works fine
// $.fn.dataTable.moment("dd.MM.yyyy");    -> Property 'moment' does not exist on type 'StaticFunctions'
($ as any).fn.dataTable.moment("dd.MM.yyyy"); //-> ERROR TypeError: jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__.fn.dataTable.moment is not a function
//(jQuery as any).fn.dataTable.moment("dd.MM.yyyy"); -> no error but seems to have no effect
this.btTable = $("#bttable").DataTable({
  order: [[2, "desc"]],
  language: this.properties.getTableDeTableLocalizationFor("Betriebsmeldungen")
});
```

I don't know what to try anymore. There seems to be some webpack? magic happening which i don't understand.

Like where is the difference using jQuery or the imported $ as an alias? They seem to reference different instances of jQuery?

So if someone could point me in the right direction here i would be very thankful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found the root of this problem.

Turns out i was missing this import:

```
import "datatables.net-plugins/sorting/datetime-moment";
```

After that everything worked as expected!

Looking back, the message `jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__.fn.dataTable.moment is not a function` should have be the clue i needed, but somehow i did not make the connection.

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error, i noticed that i used the wrong format for the moment function:

```
($ as any).fn.dataTable.moment("dd.MM.yyyy");
```

must be

```
($ as any).fn.dataTable.moment("DD.MM.YYYY");
```

And when i change both jQuery calls to jQuery. instead of $ the sorting starts working - hooray - BUT the styling of the datatable (and the datatable only!) stops working :-/

```
(jQuery as any).fn.dataTable.moment("DD.MM.YYYY");
this.btTable = jQuery("#bttable").DataTable({
  order: [[2, "desc"]],
  language: this.properties.getTableDeTableLocalizationFor("Betriebsmeldungen")
});
```

I use the bootstrap styling plugin of datatables and have the styling here:

```
"styles": [
  "src/assets/style/brand-bootstrap.css",
  "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
  "node_modules/datatables.net-bs4/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.css",
```

Again, when using `$(..).DataTable(...)` styling works but the sorting doesn't. When using `jQuery(..).DataTable(..)` styling is not used but the sorting works :-)

So the error seems to be with the loading of the libraries, i assume jQuery references some sort of global instance of jQuery - so what is the sense of using `import * as $ from "jquery"` and not just use the global one?

Answer (score 0):

As per following link:
https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/html5-data-attributes.html
Just change your code like below and it will work:

```
<td [attr.data-order]="data.createdDate">{{ data.createdDate | dateTimeFormat }}</td>
```